# TimerTask start stop only executing once

Tags: java, timertask

Problem, I can only execute my timer once. I know its because I called the function timer2.cancel(); and timer1.cancel(); :: Cancel being "Never run this ever again". I need a replacement function, one that actually stops a timer, but can be started back up again when I reschedule it. How do I go about doing that?

```
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

      if (e.getSource()==jbtStart)
      {

          System.out.println("Start is pressed");
          timer2.cancel();        
          timer1.schedule(new Task(), 0, delay);
      }

      else if (e.getSource()==jbtStop)
      {   
            System.out.println("Stop is pressed");
            timer1.cancel();        
            timer2.schedule(new Task2(), 0, delay);

      }
```

Comment: no idea, there is only codesnipped from ActionListener, no clear what is your definition(s) for java.util.Timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would cancel the TimerTasks instead of the Timers (and I would use only one Timer).

UPDATE:

```
   private Task task1;
   private Task2 task2;

 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

      if (e.getSource()==jbtStart)
      {

          System.out.println("Start is pressed");
          if (task2 != null) {
              task2.cancel();
          }
          task1 = new Task();
          timer.schedule(task1, 0, delay);
      }

      else if (e.getSource()==jbtStop)
      {   
            System.out.println("Stop is pressed");
            if (task1 != null) {
                task1.cancel();
            }
            task2 = new Task2();
            timer.schedule(task2, 0, delay);
      }
```

Comment: and how would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a new `Timer` at that point? Either that, or keep hold of the `TimerTask` as well as the timer, and cancel *that* instead of the timer itself.

As a third *possible* alternative, have a single timer task and a single timer, but make the timer task aware of what it's meant to do at any point - it looks like you're effectively toggling what you want to do each time the timer ticks. You could always keep two separate classes to separate the logical functionality, and then have a "wrapper" task which allows you to replace what behaviour is executed on each run.

Comment: If I pretend that I was going to say that, would that make me clever?